# How can I use Selenium in Python to get JavaScript element?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, parsing, web-scraping

I would like to parse "disabled", but I'm unable to do so using Beautiful Soup. How can I use Selenium in Python to parse "disabled"? The website I'm parsing: https://sport.woot.com/offers/asics-mens-clearance-calculator?ref=w_cnt_lnd_cat_sprt_18_1
                                    
                                        Size

```
                                    <select id="attr-size" name="Size">
                                        <option value="none">- Select -</option>
                                            <option value="6.5">6.5</option>
                                            <option value="8">8</option>
                                            <option value="8.5" disabled="">8.5</option>
                                            <option value="9.5">9.5</option>
                                            <option value="10">10</option>
                                            <option value="10.5">10.5</option>
                                            <option value="11">11</option>
                                            <option value="12" disabled="">12</option>
                                            <option value="13" disabled="">13</option>
                                            <option value="14" disabled="">14</option>
                                            <option value="12 Wide US">12 Wide US</option>
                                            <option value="13 (4E)" disabled="">13 (4E)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
```

attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import geckodriver_autoinstaller
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://sport.woot.com/offers/asics-mens-clearance-calculator? 
ref=w_cnt_lnd_cat_sprt_18_1")
disabled_sizes = driver.find_element_by_class_name("disabled")
my_disabled_sizes = []
try:
    for disabled_size in disabled_sizes:
        try:
            my_disabled_sizes.append(disabled_sizes.text)

        except:
            pass
except:
    pass
try:
    print(my_disabled_sizes[1:])  # skip first element then start listing 
disabled sizes
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath to get all the options with `disabled` attribute.

```
//select[@id='attr-size']/option[@disabled]
```

Here is the logic to get all disabled elements in python.

```
disabled_elems =driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@id='attr-size']/option[@disabled]")
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]